# CASE is not working and showing the NULL values when runned the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting all `NULL` values in the column. I have some data in table `species_data` like

```
| ID |     science_name_short    |database_value   |
|  1 | Rhododendron phipli       |3                |
|  2 | Rhododendron felica       |5                |
|3   | Rhododendron deron        |5                | 
|4   | Rhododendron  sednuns     |5                |
```

I have tried to bring the output as

```
| ID |       NAME                |Number|
|  1 | Rhododendron Species      |18    |
```

The SQL I tried is

```
Select sum(database_value)
 CASE when science_name_short='rhodo'
 THEN 'Rhododendron species'
END AS real_name
from species_data;
```

Comment: science_name_short='rhodo'  is never going to evaluate to true try left or substring to get first 5 characters.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY!

Comment: use like `upper(science_name_short) like upper('%rhodo%')`

Comment: Your query returns 3 columns, sum as first. But the expected result has 3 columns, sum as last.

Comment: You cannot use `SUM()` without a `GROUP BY`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html.

Comment: Your query is invalid. You are selecting the `sum(database_value)` of all records, resulting in one result row. But you are also selecting `CASE when science_name_short='rhodo' ...` Which record's `science_name_short` is this supposed to refer to?

Comment: Your problems, however, stem from an inappropriate datamodel. There is obviously a main category `'Rhododendron'`, but no reference to this. An azalea is a rhododendron, but its name doesn't start with rhodo. So extend your datamodel and querying the data will be easy. If you don't, then results can only be approximate.

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, you should extend your datamodel with categories. Otherwise you'll never know that an azalea is a rhododendron, because its name simply doesn't start with 'rhododendron'.

With your datamodel as is, if you want to sum up all plants starting with 'Rhododendron', the most simple approach is:

```
select 'Rhododendron species' as name, sum(database_value) as num
from species_data
where science_name_short like 'Rhododendron%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query, using [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate):

```
SELECT 
    MIN(ID) AS ID,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('Rhodo', science_name_short) = 1 THEN 'Rhododendron species' ELSE science_name_short END AS 'NAME',
    SUM(database_value) AS 'Number' 
FROM species_data
GROUP BY CASE WHEN LOCATE('Rhodo', science_name_short) = 1 THEN 'Rhododendron species' ELSE science_name_short END
```

---

You can also use a solution using [`LTRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) and [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
SELECT
    MIN(ID) AS ID,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(science_name_short), 5) = 'Rhodo' THEN 'Rhododendron species' ELSE science_name_short END AS 'NAME',
    SUM(database_value) AS 'Number'
FROM species_data
GROUP BY CASE WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(science_name_short), 5) = 'Rhodo' THEN 'Rhododendron species' ELSE science_name_short END
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ad33a/5/1

Comment: the inverted comma at name and number should be removed

Answer (score 0):

Use `like` of `substr()` if possible

```
Select database_value
CASE when 
upper(science_name_short) like upper('%rhodo%') THEN 'Rhododendron species'
END AS real_name
from species_data;
```

If you want to use aggregate functions like `sum()` on any column, use it with `group by`.

Comment: u can't use `sum` without `group by`, I Have edited my answer. If you need sum of database_value please add group by.

Comment: Yes you can. 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: one way or the other aggregate function should go with Group by.

Comment: @deepesh kumar: No. As P.Salmon says, it's totally valid to have a query like `select 'Rhododendron species', sum(database_value) from species_data where science_name_short like 'Rhododendron%'`. There is nothing wrong with aggregating data to a single result row.